# Why do I have to terminate R in between every Shiny app run?

Tags: r, shiny

I've been developing an array of Shiny apps over the last year in RStudio, and at some point in time, I started running into this issue where if I am running an app locally on my computer, then close out the app, I have to completely terminate R and start a new session before I can try to run the app again.

If I try to just run the app again after making some edits, the console gets stuck on runApp(). Eventually, if I try to interrupt R, the whole thing crashes. I'm not sure when this started happening and I've just been manually terminating and restarting in between runs for awhile now because I can't seem to find anything online to help me troubleshoot the issue.

Any ideas on what can cause this behavior/how I can troubleshoot?

Thanks!

### Update:

The later package does appear to work with my other apps except for one in particular that happens to be the most extensive app I've been working on. Any thoughts? Here are the libraries I load in:

```
library(systemfonts)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shinyBS)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(highcharter) 
library(kableExtra)
library(ExcelFunctionsR)
library(plotly)
library(forcats)
library(reactable)
library(openxlsx)
library(readxl)
library(gt)
library(scales)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinyscreenshot)
library(tidyverse)
library(network)
library(networkD3)
library(igraph)
library(reactable)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(stringr)
library(DBI)
library(rlang)
library(htmltools)
library(later)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the solution posted on Posit Community: [R Crashes Shiny App](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-crashes-when-closing-shiny-app-window-instead-of-clicking-red-stop-button-in-rstudio/131951)

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage()
server <- function(input, output, session) {  
 session$onSessionEnded(function() { stopApp() })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The related issue has been solved on GitHub (https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2081).

To fix it you might need to get the latest version of "later" package, which is utilized by Shiny.

```
devtools::install_github('r-lib/later')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can now run and re-run the Shiny app template that uses Old Faithful Geyser data and shiny::runExample('01_hello'), but my other apps will still crash R in between runs.

Comment: Another potential reason could be that your  display driver needs an update (Device Manager -> Display Adapters -> <your-graphics-unit> -> Update Driver).

Comment: I'm currently using the generic drivers included with macOS Moneterey 12.1 and don't seem to have any updates I can run.

Comment: That issue is from may 2018 and was fixed in `later` version [0.7.3](https://github.com/r-lib/later/issues/57#issuecomment-460358833) currently version 1.3.0 is on CRAN.

Comment: I currently have version 1.3.0 installed.